# Visual Studio sees error in my web.configs

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

My app works, it builds and runs fine, but when I look at web.config file in the editor, it finds all these syntax errors:

[image]

Why does it say there are syntax errors when there are not?

Comment: Looks like it's not opening in the XML editor. What happens if you right click the file and select "Open with..." then choose the "XML (Text) Editor"?

Comment: wow that was it. I just assumed VS would do that automatically since it an autogenerated file and everything. I choose set as default so it should open all .config files as xml? is there a way to say only open asp config and config transforms as xml or is it only by extension?

Comment: It's by file extension, but all `.config` files should be XML anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems your Visual Studio is not opening config files in the XML editor. To fix this:

1. Right click the `web.config` file and select "Open with..."
2. Choose `XML (Text) Editor`
3. Click the <kbd>Set as Default</kbd> button

Now it will open the files correctly.

Comment: I only asked about file extension because I suppose it could be possible Id have a config for a weird package that isn't xml

Comment: The file extension thing is just how VS works. Even in a vanilla install if you had some weird format inside a `.config` file, it would be opened in the XML editor.